# How to create a Marquee animation with angular CDK?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I will receive content of a dynamic size and this content will be constantly updated by websocket.

In addition, you must have the effect of the marquee, where it looks like an airport sign, starting from the end on the right and going to the left infinitely in an infinite effect.

This will be for stock exchange assets, so whenever you reach the end of the list you must start over at the beginning, I only managed to get to the code below, but it has many problems:

**HTML**

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="list-container list-group" orientation="horizontal" [itemSize]="($asyncData | async)?.length">
        <ul>
          <li *cdkVirtualFor="let data of $asyncData | async; templateCacheSize: ($asyncData | async)?.length;">
            <span>X</span>
            <span>Y</span>
            <span>Z</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    interval(600).pipe(filter(() => !!this.viewport)).subscribe(e =>   {
    this.viewport.scrollToIndex(this._elementIndex, 'smooth');
     this._elementIndex += 1;
    })
  }
```